# Script doesn't run anymore after upgrading to python 3.7.3

Tags: visual-studio, syntax

Just a beginner question, I upgraded python from 2.7.10 to python 3.7.3. 
Ran some scripts but nothing works anymore. So in the basis entered this code to check:

```
a=("hello world")
print(a)
```

and still gets the error of

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Gijs-2:visual code studio Gijs$ print(a)bash: syntax error near unexpected token `a'
```

also with scripts as:

```
name = input("Give me your name: ")
print("Your name is " + name)
```

I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Gijs-2:visual code studio Gijs$ print("Your name is " + name)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Your name is "'
```

Can someone help me? It's really frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two (independent?) issues here:

- Python 2.x and 3.x are not compatible. There have been syntax and library changes which mean you cannot run a 2.x script on 3.x or vice versa and expect it to work. You can consider the two as different, but related, languages. To that end, you should generally *never* remove any version of Python that comes with the system, and instead install other major versions side-by-side. Removing existing versions tends to break system scripts (on many Linux distros).

  - If you are not a programmer, and only wish to run an existing script, you should install the correct version of Python for that script. If it's a Python 2 script, stay within the Python 2 branch.
- Your error is coming from `bash`. This suggests that you are not running your code in Python, but rather Bash. I would suggest you try running the command `python` (or maybe `python3`) to get a Python prompt and see if that works first. Depending on how you installed Python, it is entirely possible that `python` only maps to Python 2, and you need the more explicit `python3` command to get 3.

  - Once you have figured out whether you even have Python installed correctly, you can take a look at why the Visual Studio Code launch config may be trying to launch the wrong interpreter, and configure it to launch the correct one.

Comment: I believe that Visual Studio Code is calling '/usr/bin/python2' or whatever the path was, which no longer exists, so it just tries to run directly in bash instead. If so, I'd be possibly useful to raise a bug about that behaviour, as I can imagine some instances where running the code under the wrong interpreter could be rather bad.